# How to remove a file from url using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want `http://www.foo.com/` to internally point to `/var/www/home.php` and `http://www.foo.com/home.php` to be redirected to `http://www.foo.com/`.

Thus, I would like to fix the old `http://www.foo.com/home.php` to the new one `http://www.foo.com/`. But I always get infinite loop or other strange error no matter what.

Comment: What rule are you trying, so we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want home.php to be the directory index (as opposed to the usual index.php, etc), you don't need the overhead of mod_rewrite to do it:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php index.php index.html // and so on
```

It works in directory .htaccess files too, if you want to maintain a different default elsewhere. More details via [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your virtualhost definition for foo.com:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
```

Then your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/home.php$ /
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will redirect from foo.com to home.php then it would ofcourse go in to infinite loop. Rather try to include the `home.php` page in the index page of `foo.com/`